# （monaca）バックグラウンドで位置情報を10秒ごとに取れる？

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaでハイブリッドアプリを開発しています。
現在具現したい機能はバックグラウンドの状態で位置情報をとってサーバに送ることです。
アプリを起動したあと、ホームボタンを押してバックグラウンド状態になったとき、１０秒ごとに位置情報をとってサーバに送ることができるのか知りたいです。
もし、参考できるサンプルコードがありましたら、教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず初めに、Monacaはバックグラウンドでの動作をサポートしていませんので、思い通りに動作させることは難しいかもしれません。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/faq/application/#can-i-develop-applications-that-run-in-the-background

実現する方法として`pause`イベントで`interval`を発火させる方法を思いつきましたが、少なくともiOSでは`pause`ハンドラ内でcordovaのAPIを呼び出すことはできませんでした。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/events/events/#ios

手元に端末が無いため未検証ですが、Androidなら次のようなコードで動くかもしれません。このままだと`pause`のたびに`interval`が新しく起動するので、何らかの方法で古い`interval`を止める必要がありますが。

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
  setInterval(function(){
  // Your code here
  }, 10000);
}, false);
```